# Hiding navigation bar with a segmented control right under the bar

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Here's the set up

Navigation Bar

segmented control

Table view

I know in iOS 8 there is the navigationBar.hidesOnSwipe function that works wonders.

Is there a way, perhaps using autolayout, to also hide the segmented control as the navigationBar hides as well without writing a custom function to handle this?

Also, when I make the following setup in a storyboard, swiping the table view does not hide the navigation bar but swiping the segmented control does. But when I turn .hidesOnTap, the navigationBar hides and pulls the segmentedcontrol up

Thanks in advance